# Python - Filtering conditions efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: '2012-03-02',  1: '2012-04-01',  2: '2012-04-12',  3: '2012-04-14',  4: '2012-04-21',  5: '2012-05-12',  6: '2012-06-23',  7: '2012-06-25',  8: '2012-06-26',  9: '2012-06-27'},
                   'type': {0: 'Holiday',  1: 'Other',  2: 'Event',  3: 'Holiday',  4: 'Event',  5: 'Holiday',  6: 'Other',  7: 'Holiday',  8: 'Holiday',  9: 'Event'},
                   'locale': {0: 'Local',  1: 'Regional',  2: 'National',  3: 'Local',  4: 'National',  5: 'National',  6: 'National',  7: 'Regional',  8: 'Regional',  9: 'Local'}})
```

And this function:

```
def preprocess(data_input):
    data = data_input.copy()
    
    conditions = [
        (data['type'] ==  'Holiday') & (data.locale == 'National'),
        (data['type'] ==  'Holiday') & (data.locale == 'Regional'),
        (data['type'] ==  'Holiday') & (data.locale == 'Local')
        ]
    values = [3,2,1]

    data.loc[:,'Holiday'] = np.select(conditions, values, default=0)
    
    
    conditions = [
        (data['type'] ==  'Event') & (data.locale == 'National'),
        (data['type'] ==  'Event') & (data.locale == 'Regional'),
        (data['type'] ==  'Event') & (data.locale == 'Local')
        ]
    values = [3,2,1]

    data.loc[:,'Events'] = np.select(conditions, values, default=0)

    return(data)
```

When I run this function over df I will get:

```
preprocess(df)
```

[image]

Which is the expected result. However, I'm wondering about efficiency and best practices. I feel that both `conditions` use too many lines of code and that they could be written more elegant and efficiently, but I can't figure out how. I tried with `np.where()` but I struggled when I found out I would have to filter the data frames in each argument.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `Series.map` with `Series.where`

```py
locale_map = {'National': '3',
              'Regional': '2',
              'Local': '1'}

df['Holiday'] = df['locale'].map(locale_map).where(df['type'].eq('Holiday'), 0)
df['Events'] = df['locale'].map(locale_map).where(df['type'].eq('Event'), 0)
```

```
print(df)

         date     type    locale Holiday Events
0  2012-03-02  Holiday     Local       1      0
1  2012-04-01    Other  Regional       0      0
2  2012-04-12    Event  National       0      3
3  2012-04-14  Holiday     Local       1      0
4  2012-04-21    Event  National       0      3
5  2012-05-12  Holiday  National       3      0
6  2012-06-23    Other  National       0      0
7  2012-06-25  Holiday  Regional       2      0
8  2012-06-26  Holiday  Regional       2      0
9  2012-06-27    Event     Local       0      1
```

Answer (score 2):

Overall I think your code looks fine, it's readable and easily understandable.  In terms of efficiency, you're using boolean masks for your conditions and not committing any sort of pandas performance anti-pattern that I can see.

One major-ish pandas issue is that you have a redundant call to `copy()`.  This isn't cheap, it results in Python creating a deep copy of your whole dataframe.  It's also not necessary, you can just return the modified df rather than making a new copy the whole time and returning it.  This is pretty standard style in pandas, it's why pandas operations usually look like `df = df.do_a_thing()`.  The new value of `df` is returned via `do_a_thing()` rather than modified in place.  (The `in_place` flag exists for a lot of methods, but it isn't the default for a reason).

One nitpick I'd say is to be explicit when using categorical variables.  Your `values` variable is a categorical variable that's derived conditionally from the dataframe, but you are treating it as a series of integers.

In terms of general software engineering, there is one clear area of improvement that I can see.  Your preprocess method is duplicating code for a singular purpose.  I have refactored it such that the `preprocess` method takes the `type_column` (e.g. 'Holiday' and 'Event') as a parameter, and applies the transformation after that.  Now if you have an issue with your `preprocess` logic, or want to make a change, you'll only need to do it in one area rather than two.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: '2012-03-02',  1: '2012-04-01',  2: '2012-04-12',  3: '2012-04-14',  4: '2012-04-21',  5: '2012-05-12',  6: '2012-06-23',  7: '2012-06-25',  8: '2012-06-26',  9: '2012-06-27'},
                   'type': {0: 'Holiday',  1: 'Other',  2: 'Event',  3: 'Holiday',  4: 'Event',  5: 'Holiday',  6: 'Other',  7: 'Holiday',  8: 'Holiday',  9: 'Event'},
                   'locale': {0: 'Local',  1: 'Regional',  2: 'National',  3: 'Local',  4: 'National',  5: 'National',  6: 'National',  7: 'Regional',  8: 'Regional',  9: 'Local'}})


def preprocess(data, type_column):
    conditions = [
        (data['type'] == type_column) & (data.locale == 'National'),
        (data['type'] == type_column) & (data.locale == 'Regional'),
        (data['type'] == type_column) & (data.locale == 'Local')
    ]
    # These values are categorical variables, (i.e. it's dependent on the combination of two columns).
    # Better to be explicit about what type they are rather than leaving them as ints.
    values = pd.Categorical([3, 2, 1])

    data.loc[:, type_column] = np.select(conditions, values, default=0)

    return data


df = preprocess(df, 'Holiday')
df = preprocess(df, 'Event')
print(df)
```

Comment: I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73431588/python-function-ram-memory-efficiency/) a specific question for this `.copy()` issue. Anyways, the reason because I do the `.copy()` method is because if I don't use it, I always receive an `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

Answer (score 1):

Two part answer, how to apply the function and how to improve memory use with right pandas dtype.

### Data transform:

One-liner using [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and a dict for mapping the values. This method avoids `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

```
r_map = {
        "National": "3",
        "Regional": "2",
        "Local": "1",
    }


df = df.assign(
    Holiday=df.locale.where(df.type == "Holiday", 0).replace(r_map),
    Events=df.locale.where(df.type == "Event", 0).replace(r_map),
)
```

|  | date | type | locale | Holiday | Events |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2012-03-02 | Holiday | Local | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2012-04-01 | Other | Regional | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2012-04-12 | Event | National | 0 | 3 |
| 3 | 2012-04-14 | Holiday | Local | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 2012-04-21 | Event | National | 0 | 3 |
| 5 | 2012-05-12 | Holiday | National | 3 | 0 |
| 6 | 2012-06-23 | Other | National | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 2012-06-25 | Holiday | Regional | 2 | 0 |
| 8 | 2012-06-26 | Holiday | Regional | 2 | 0 |
| 9 | 2012-06-27 | Event | Local | 0 | 1 |

### Memory Efficiency:

Using the appropriate pandas dtype for columns with strings that are repeated can save a large amount of memory. Pandas defaults to rather high precision and generality in the dtypes for a newly created dataframe:

```
s_float = pd.Series(0.001).dtype
> dtype('float64')
```

Same with textual data in columns:

```
s_text = pd.Series("Thy").dtype
> dtype: object
```

The `object` dtype is a very general container for pretty much anything we like and isn't very optimized. In particular for the example in op's post where we have multiple columns where the values are mostly similar, we can gain a lot by using pandas category datatype. In this example below, based on data from OP's post we're using 7x memory footprint for date, type, and locale columns by using `object` instead of `category` dtype.

```
df_large = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[[0]]).reindex(range(99999), method="ffill")

for col in df_large.columns:
    df_large[col] = df_large[col].transform(lambda x: df[col].sample(1).values[0])
print("Without category: ")
print(df_large.memory_usage().iloc[1:])
print(df_large.dtypes)

for col in df_large.columns:
    if type(df[col].iloc[0]) == str:
        df_large[col] = df_large[col].astype("category")

print("       ")
print("With category: ")
print(df_large.memory_usage().iloc[1:])
print(df_large.dtypes)
```

---

```
Without category: 
date      799992
type      799992
locale    799992

date      object
type      object
locale    object
       
With category: 
date      100379
type      100131
locale    100131

date      category
type      category
locale    category
```